# How can I efficiently check if two files are identical?

Tags: rust, diff, file-access

I want to compare two files to determine if they are identical. Somehow, if I use Robocopy with Windows, it is able to do this almost instantly. I, on the other hand, cannot even come close. For example, the following code-block takes about 4 seconds to run on a 250MB file:

```rust
let mut file = match OpenOptions::new().read(true).write(false).open(file_name) {
    Ok(n) => n,
    Err(_) => panic!("Could not read file!"),
};
let mut buffer = Vec::new();
file.read_to_end(&mut buffer);
for _ in buffer.iter() {}
```

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: For performance-related questions, you should also include how you are **building** and **running** the code. Ideally you'd also explain your testbed setup (processor, OS, drives, memory, etc.).

Comment: there's a chance that producing and comparing their hashes could make things faster? it would require maybe less memory problems, anyway I can't help actually but just wished to add an humble thought

Comment: It's possible that Robocopy is able to take advantage of file system level deduplication, checksums, or some such detail that means it doesn't have to read the files to know if they're identical. It's very difficult to know, absent more context, whether that 4 seconds is an absolute limitation and you have to "cheat" to beat it, if a better algorithm (like hashing both files first) would help, or if your Rust code is just slow for some reason.

Comment: *Robocopy [...] is able to do this almost instantly* — I'd expect it to have deeper hooks into the operating system or file system, allowing to query metadata that it could use to avoid looking at each byte. Try creating two 250MB files that differ in only their last byte and see how that time compares.

Comment: @DiegoDeVita I'd expect that hashing would be slower for the example shown here which compares one file against another file, exactly one time. Creating the hash requires reading *every* byte; comparing for equality can stop at the first mismatch, which may even be the first byte of the file. Hashing is likely to speed things up as soon as you have to perform two or more comparisons.

Comment: Yes I agree, of course it's more time consuming but I was supposing that maybe it's easier to produce 2 hashes and compare them instead of comparing two files. When I say easier I mean more friendly with memory. Of course on both cases you have to visit each single byte contained in both files. But yes I agree it was a dumb consideration.

Comment: Do note you don't need to store the whole file in memory *at once* to compare them byte by byte; it's probably slightly faster to go in chunks (the size of the chunk dependent on various X-factors). But not likely faster by 4 seconds than using `read_to_end`.

Comment: @trent I totally agree with your point and I would even try something like [`mmap`](https://docs.rs/memmap/0.7.0/memmap/struct.Mmap.html) to avoid any allocation/copy.

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm not entirely sure how to include reproducible code since there are networked files involved. I can tell you that the speed is considerably faster on a local file than on a networked file. But, I can also say that Robocopy doesn't have this issue. Plus, my code, currently only looks at one file, Robocopy is doing both.

Comment: I will play with not using `read_to_end` and compare, perhaps that is the issue.

Answer (score 4):

First, it's clear that if the 2 files have different sizes, you can very quickly establish that by simply looking up their metadata from the file system, w/o actually touching the files' contents/data. Also, I will assume we are talking about true bit-by-bit comparison of files. Some tools for file comparison perform a superficial check, which is fast but not thorough enough to guarantee 100% accuracy.

Generally, to avoid loading the whole files in memory, you can read from them simultaneously, in blocks of the same size. That has another benefit - if there is a difference at the beginning, this approach will probably be faster. But it is important to note, that you should read the files in chunks, not byte-by-byte. If you do that, comparing is trivial. Let's say you read data into two `Vec<u8>`s of the same size. Even a simple iteration in a plain-old `for` loop will be extremely fast (like `v1[i] != v2[i]`). But, of course, make sure you're benchmarking your app in *release* mode, not *debug* mode!

If you do the above, your application logic will have a negligible impact on the CPU. Your bottleneck will be the IO. It's important to note that a huge factor will be the OS cache. If your files go into the OS cache, your app will run much faster but even then the bottleneck will be in the IO, not your actual comparison logic (whether you're using a simple byte-by-byte comparison in a loop or some sort of direct byte-blocks comparison).

Comment: It sounds like I definitely need to work with reading block-by-block instead of all at once. I will work on that. But, it seems the bigger issue is the "superficial" check that both you and @Shepmaster mentioned. I ran some more testing with Robocopy and it's definitely reading meta-data on the files to determine whether it should copy a file.

Comment: Why cant use do a md5 hash and compare the results.

Comment: @vizsatiz You could, but that would always require reading the *entire* contents of both files + there would be a slight CPU overhead for computing the MD5 hashes.

Answer (score 1):

the fail fast solution
*read the files buffer by buffer and stop reading if this buffers are not equal*

```
…
if let Result::Ok(file1) = File::open(file_name1) {
    let mut reader1 = BufReader::new(file1);
    if let Result::Ok(file2) = File::open(file_name2) {
        let mut reader2 = BufReader::new(file2);
        let mut buf1 = [0; 10000];
        let mut buf2 = [0; 10000];
        loop {
            if let Result::Ok(n1) = reader1.read(&mut buf1) {
                if n1 > 0 {
                    if let Result::Ok(n2) = reader2.read(&mut buf2) {
                        if n1 == n2 {
                            if buf1 == buf2 {
                                continue;
                            }
                        }
                        println!("not equal");
                        return;
                    }
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        println!("equal");
        return;
    };
};
eprintln!("oops!");
```